Pandas Export to Excel with MultiIndex Column with Formatting
I have a dataframe in Pandas which groups shift attendance for specific days
DAYS = ['26-Aug','27-Aug','28-Aug']
SHIFTS = ['S1','S2','S3']
EMPLOYEES = ['John Doe','Jane Doe']

# Create Column Index of shifts for each day
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([DAYS, SHIFTS], names=['Days','Shifts'])
# Create df for each employee
df = pd.DataFrame('', EMPLOYEES, idx)
# ... fill df based on certain conditions I have ...

Here is an example of what the output would look like when i do `df.to_excel('output.xlsx')

However I am looking to format the excel output using xlsxwriter so I can add some formatting/color to some of the specific rows/columns.
I made this function as an easy way to output to Excel but having the data returned as a table with autofit column widths. However does not seem to play nice with my dataframe because of the MultiIndex column.
def createExcel(df, filename, sheet_name):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine="xlsxwriter")
    df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=1, header=False, index=False)

    # Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

    # Get the dimensions of the dataframe.
    (max_row, max_col) = df.shape

    # Create a list of column headers, to use in add_table().
    column_settings = [{"header": column} for column in df.columns]

    # Add the Excel table structure. Pandas will add the data.
    worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {"columns": column_settings})

    # Make the columns wider for clarity.
    worksheet.autofit()

    writer.close()

I get an error NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented.. If I change index=True, I get another error because of how I set the header in column_settings (df.columns returns tuple, not just column name).
My question is, how can I output this to spreadsheet combined with worksheet.add_table() and worksheet.autofit()?

To use worksheet.add_table() you need to transform multi-index to single index because when you pass MultiIndex columns to worksheet.add_table(), it expects a flat list of headers.
flat_columns = ['{}_{}'.format(*col) for col in df.columns]
df.columns = flat_columns

Manually set the column headers
for col_num, header in enumerate(df.columns, 0):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num, header)

Here is code that works on the given data:
def createExcel(df, filename, sheet_name):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine="xlsxwriter")

    flat_columns = ['{}_{}'.format(*col) for col in df.columns]
    df.columns = flat_columns

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=1, header=False, index=False)

    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

    (max_row, max_col) = df.shape

    column_settings = [{"header": column} for column in df.columns]

    worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {"columns": column_settings})
    for col_num, header in enumerate(df.columns, 0):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num, header)

    worksheet.autofit()

    writer.close()

